# Using the map() function to list data from firestore. It's only showing one post instead of all of them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, frontend

I'm trying to get the data 'answer' to show from my firestore database but instead it is only showing the first post. I'm sure it is because of how i'm implementing the map() function. I'm not calling the function to allow it to list under each answer instead it's listing for just one and I'm not sure what to change to make it for each answer.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    if (questionId) {
      db.collection("questions")
        .doc(questionId)
        .collection("answer")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          if (mounted) {
            setGetAnswer(
              snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                id: doc.id,
                answers: doc.data(),
              }))
            );
          }
        });
    }

 loadQuestionAnswer();

    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, [questionId]);

  const loadQuestionAnswer = () => {
    dispatch(
      setQuestionInfo({
        questionId: Id,
        questionName: question,
      })
    );
  };
```

Here is the the div where the map() function is called:

```
return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="post__info">
      </div>
      <div className="post__body">
        <div className="post__question">
          <p>{question}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="post__answer">
          {getAnswer.map(({ id, answers }) => (
            <p key={id} style={{ position: "relative", paddingBottom: "20px" }}>
              {Id === answers.questionId ? (
                <span>
                  {parse(answers.answer)}
                  <br />
                  <span
                  >
                    <span
                    >
                      {answers.user.displayName
                        ? answers.user.displayName
                        : answers.user.email}{" "}
                      on{" "}
                      {new Date(answers.timestamp?.toDate()).toLocaleString()}
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </span>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="post__questionAnswer">
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Probably`Id === answers.questionId` statement is only matching for your first answer. Have you checked the value of `Id` and `answers.questionId` for rest of your answers ?

Comment: Do you mean check via console log or another comparative check?

Comment: Logging would give fast insights

Comment: so the console log revealed that the Id shows all of the question ids but the answers.questionId only shows the Id of the first question

Comment: I think technically `answers.questionId` will be same for all answers since they belong to one question. I am not sure what exactly `Id` is ? Since I can't see it being set in the shared code anywhere.

Comment: Id is the unique id for each question. Yea I think that's why it is only showing the id for one question in the console log. I think how i'm calling the answers via snapshot may be incorrect? What do you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue actually was a mishap on my part. I introduced a userSelector (redux) for the questionId that would choose the post's id once the post was clicked. Once I deleted questionId and replaced it with Id it worked. Id was the question's ID select from firebase.